# How to copy to array in C?

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
for( i = 0; i < m; ++i){
        for( j = 0; j < m && index[x[i]][j] >= 0; ++j){
            printf("%d ", index[x[i]][j]);
        }
}
```

In the above, I need all the values of index[x[i]][j] into one single dimension array, say B[].

Assigning the value of b[j] will only copy have the values.

Comment: Btw, if `index` (shouldn't the name rather be `array`??) is a truly a 2-dimensional array the data is actually contiguous in memory, i.e. you can just iterate over it `n*m` times, starting at `(int *)index`.

Comment: @PeterSchneider he is also re-ordering the elements while copying. Note x[i]

Comment: Ah. Oh. It *is* an index array. I should read more carefully. I somehow do not understand the question actually, partly because there is no question, and partly because the last sentence is agrammatical. Ok, there is a question in the title -- the answer is "either element-wise or by memcpy".

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to store in row-major order and you have m rows and n columns, this should do the copy :

```
for( i = 0; i < m; ++i){
    for( j = 0; j < n; ++j){
        b[i*n + j] = index[x[i]][j];
    }
}
```

make sure that b has size m*n. e.g. `int b[m*n];`

Also in your code you are only printing non-negative numbers. If you only want to copy non-negative values, you probably want to set some default value in b for that case.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, as you are using `int arrays`, use a [memcpy](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html).

If you want to copy all of the values in the 2d array(**copy continuous memory** ), this method works.

> The memcpy() function copies n bytes from memory area src to memory
>          area dest.  The memory areas must not overlap.  Use memmove(3) if the
>          memory areas do overlap.

```
memcpy(B, index, sizeof(index[0][0])*m*m)
```

Comment: Generally an excellent suggestion. Not in this case though. Note the array of indexes `x`. Basically Vidya doesn't want to copy continuous memory

Comment: The array is completely -1, upon print.

Comment: Which array is empty? @Vidya

Comment: the B array, after memcpy()

Comment: It shouldn't happen. Have you initialized the B to size m*m?

Comment: yes, I have. The B is of size 1000 in this particular case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92123/discussion-between-vidya-and-luoluo).

Answer (score 2):

You can have a separate variable for the b array indexing. And assign the values to the b array. Like below.

```
int pos=0;
for( i = 0; i < m; ++i){
    for( j = 0; j < n; ++j){
        b[pos++] = index[x[i]][j];
    } 
}
```

This will assign all the values in the index[x[i]][j] to the one dimensional array b.